# findall() returning whole string instead of list

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex in Python to match a string:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+?\,\s[a-zA-Z]+?\,\s\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})")
string = '[ 1234, jack, 1987-09-02]'
ret = pattern.findall(string)
```

This returns the whole string as the list element:
['1234, jack, 1987-09-02']

but i am trying to get a list with each match as an element:
['1234', 'jack', '1987-09-02']

I know '+' is greedy but i added '?'

Comment: Did you mean [`string = '[ 1234, jack, 1987-09-02]'`](http://ideone.com/XFRBVS)?

Comment: sorry, yes... somehow that got deleted when i posted it

Comment: You can add the line  result = ret[0].split (','). Is it an acceptable solution for you or not ?

Comment: Maybe just [`pattern = re.compile(r"[\w-]+")`](http://ideone.com/ghjK73) will do?

Comment: OR [`string.strip(' []').split(', ')`](http://ideone.com/wG8xhu)?

Comment: pattern = re.compile(r"[\w-]+") works thanks but why does mine not work.  what am i doing wrong

Comment: See [your pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD0hH8/1) - you just matched the whole string inside `[...]` while you need to get the chunks only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern matches the whole contents inside the square brackets, while you seem to want to only get the character chunks that consist of word and hyphen characters.

Use

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[\w-]+")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK4pJ1/1)

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ghjK73):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"[\w-]+")
string = '[ 1234, jack, 1987-09-02]'
ret = pattern.findall(string)
print(ret)
# => ['1234', 'jack', '1987-09-02']
```

Pattern details: `[\w-]` is a character class matching a word character (a digit, letter or underscore) one or more number of times (due to the `+` quantifier).

**An alternative solution**: Match optional whitespaces and then match and capture all non-comma symbols with

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\s*([^[\],]+)")
```

See another [regex](https://regex101.com/r/xD0hH8/1) and [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/NZX1yc) demos. `re.findall` only returns captured values into Groups 1+, so only what was captured with `(...)` (i.e. all 1+ characters other than `]`, `[` and `,` will be returned).

Comment: how about "[1234, Jack, 1987-09-02 10:40:41] [Michigan] lights: Repair was Completed - Elasped time: 00:02:34.0379717 [Test.Run()]" to ['1234', 'Jack', '1987-09-02', '10:40:41', 'Michigan', 'lights: Repair was Completed - Elasped time: 00:02:34.0379717 [Test.Run()]']  Your alternative solution almost works

Comment: I have no idea what you expect to obtain from this string. It has a much more complicated structure.

Comment: Just trying to split it into a list as in the list after the 'to'

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to match once, use [`search`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#re.regex.search) instead of `findall` and introduce groups ([live demo](http://ideone.com/gXdkQ2)):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '[ 1234, jack, 1987-09-02]'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+?),\s([a-zA-Z]+?),\s(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})")
>>> pattern.search(string).groups()
('1234', 'jack', '1987-09-02')
```

[`groups`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#re.match.groups) returns a tuple instead of a list, which means the result can be destructured (like `number, name, birthday = pattern.search(string).groups()`) or passed around, but not added to. If you really need a list, simply use `list(pattern.search(string).groups())`.

Comment: This does not return a list.

Comment: @CPL Added more information and a way to get a list. Most likely, a tuple is preferable, but if you really want a list, it's very easy to get.